# Scrapy CONCURRENT_REQUESTS and DOWNLOAD_DELAY not working

Tags: python, url, concurrency, scrapy, delay

This is my code snippet

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 25,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 100,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0
    }

    f = open("list.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath("//div[@class='border block']"):
            urlgem = quote.xpath(".//div[@class='col-md-4 pull-right']/a/@href").extract()
            if urlgem:
                yield {
                    'text': urlgem,
                }
```

Using Terminal I execute above code using command

```
scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json
```

list.txt contains 50 URL of same domain separated by lines

As per my understanding the code should put 25 requests to the domain for 25 URL (from a list of 50 URL) and should complete in 2-3 seconds time span and generate file name quotes.json

The output in file quotes.json is coming out as expected but SCRAPY is not performing the task concurrently instead it is fetching URL one by one and takes approximately 55-60 seconds to complete.

Another code that I wrote using BeautifulSoup performing same task as above

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://SOMEWEBSITE.com/search_by='
all_urls = list()

def generate_urls():
    for i in range(480882, 480983):
        all_urls.append(base_url + str(i))

def scrape(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    pageText = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'border block'})

    for bidBox in pageText:
        bidNumber = bidBox.find('p', {'class': 'bid_no pull-left'})
        print(bidNumber.text)
        bidStatus = bidBox.find('span', {'class': 'text-success'})
        print(bidStatus.text)

generate_urls()

p = Pool(50)
p.map(scrape, all_urls)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Above code executed in terminal using command

```
python3 quotes.py
```

Above also produce same result. The output is as expected but the execution time is approx. 1 URL per second.

Please help!!!

Comment: Any positive response please??

Comment: I have some thoughts about it. But I need some more info. Especially scrapy log output.
Special attention to:
time from the moment when you entered console scrapy command to first log line ouptut.
time from log message `Spider opened` to `Spider closed`.
And log stats (ending log lines).